# Parameterize both class and tests in JUnit 5

Tags: java, junit5, parameterized-unit-test

Is there a way to parameterize both test class (like you could do with `Parameterized` and `@Parameters` in JUnit 4) and test methods (like you could do with JUnitParams in JUnit 4 or with `@ParameterizedTest` in JUnit 5)? I need to get the Cartesian product of the parameters in the end.

Example of a partial test for `java.nio.ByteBuffer` using the desired approach:

```
public class ByteBufferTest {
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 16384;
    private final ByteOrder byteOrder;
    private ByteBuffer sut;

    @Factory(dataProvider = "byteOrders")
    public ByteBufferTest(ByteOrder byteOrder) {
        this.byteOrder = byteOrder;
    }

    @DataProvider
    public static Object[][] byteOrders() {
        return new Object[][] {
                {ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN},
                {ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN}
        };
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        sut = ByteBuffer.allocate(BUFFER_SIZE);
        sut.order(byteOrder);
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "validPositions")
    public void position(int position) {
        System.out.println(byteOrder + " position " + position);
        sut.position(position);
        assertThat(sut.position()).isEqualTo(position);
    }

    @DataProvider
    public static Object[][] validPositions() {
        return new Object[][] {{0}, {1}, {BUFFER_SIZE - 1}};
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "intPositionsAndValues")
    public void putInt(int position, int value, byte[] expected) {
        System.out.println(byteOrder + " position " + position + " value " + value);
        sut.putInt(position, value);
        assertThat(sut.array())
                .contains(expected[0], atIndex(position))
                .contains(expected[1], atIndex(position + 1))
                .contains(expected[2], atIndex(position + 2))
                .contains(expected[3], atIndex(position + 3));
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] intPositionsAndValues() {
        if (byteOrder == ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN) {
            return new Object[][]{
                    {0, 0, new byte[4]},
                    {5, 123456789, new byte[] {0x07, 0x5B, (byte) 0xCD, 0x15}},
            };
        } else {
            return new Object[][]{
                    {0, 0, new byte[4]},
                    {5, 123456789, new byte[] {0x15, (byte) 0xCD, 0x5B, 0x07}},
            };
        }
    }
}
```

It produces:

```
LITTLE_ENDIAN position 0
LITTLE_ENDIAN position 1
LITTLE_ENDIAN position 16383
BIG_ENDIAN position 0
BIG_ENDIAN position 1
BIG_ENDIAN position 16383
LITTLE_ENDIAN position 0 value 0
LITTLE_ENDIAN position 5 value 123456789
BIG_ENDIAN position 0 value 0
BIG_ENDIAN position 5 value 123456789
```

We're thinking about migrating to JUnit 5 from TestNG, but we use this kind of thing pretty often. The use of the byte order as a class-level parameter in the example above is not a coincidence: we often need tests for various binary data processor, where the test constructor would take a byte/bit order argument, and we run every test for both Big Endian and Little Endian.

I was thinking about creating an extension for this and then use `ExtendWith`, but maybe there is an existing extension or something that works out-of-the-box that I have missed?

Comment: Why don't you just merge each of them into one `Object[]` of the parameters in the `testParameters` method?

Comment: @daniu, because typically there is much more than a single method. It would be a clear violation of the DRY principle.

Comment: How so? Creating a `CombinedDataProvider` which accepts an arbitray number of `Supplier<Object[]>`s and merges them into into a matrix of all of them seems pretty simple and non-RY. You could add it with a `@Rule`.

Comment: @daniu, interesting. I'll look into it, but it's still not completely DRY: if I have one more class-level parameter, I'd have to add it to every single method's signature. And it looks a bit over-complicated to me, with all the rules and suppliers. Too much plumbing for such a seemingly simple task.

Comment: If you have two levels of argument, you can write it yourself a custom source that accept 1st and 2nd level then merge it to produced the desired data source while still commits with to DRY, instead of insisting on looking for a class level param. I couldn't see any value of the parameterized test class params.

Comment: @DuongNguyen I honestly don't see anything DRY about writing `ByteOrder bo,` in every test method's signature. Or using an artificial class `ClassParams` for that, in case I want to add parameters later. Besides, it's a feature supported by both JUnit 4 and TestNG, why would they support it if it was useless?

Comment: Currently, classes cannot be parameterized, but there are plans to change that: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/878#issuecomment-354544841

Comment: I wanted a similar test setup as you @SergeiTachenov . Only thing different was that I wanted the class parameters in a base class and testparams in derived class. Is it possible to do so ? 
I tried but its not working. Error is telling that actual and formal arguments differ on the base class constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### JUnit Jupiter (Vanilla)

You can combine multiple sources within e.g. a `@MethodSource`. Based on your TestNG example:

```java
class ExampleTest {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("args")
    void test(String classParameter, String testParameter) {
        System.out.println(classParameter + " " + testParameter);
    }

    static Stream<Arguments> args() {
        return classParameters().flatMap(
                classParameter -> testParameters().map(
                        testParameter -> Arguments.of(classParameter, testParameter)));
    }

    static Stream<String> classParameters() {
        return Stream.of("classParam1", "classParam2");
    }

    static Stream<String> testParameters() {
        return Stream.of("testParam1", "testParam2");
    }

}
```

This produces:

```
classParam1 testParam1
classParam1 testParam2
classParam2 testParam1
classParam2 testParam2
```

As requested by the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952884/parameterize-both-class-and-tests-in-junit-5#comment101747404_57648088), here is "an example with at least two test methods with different set of parameters":

```java
class ExampleTest {

    static Stream<String> classParams() {
        return Stream.of("classParam1", "classParam2", "classParam3");
    }

    static Stream<Arguments> withClassParams(List<?> methodParams) {
        return classParams().flatMap(
                classParam -> methodParams.stream().map(
                        methodParam -> Arguments.of(classParam, methodParam)));
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource
    void booleanParams(String classParam, boolean booleanParam) {
        System.out.println(classParam + " " + booleanParam);
    }

    static Stream<Arguments> booleanParams() {
        return withClassParams(List.of(false, true));
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource
    void integerParams(String classParam, int integerParam) {
        System.out.println(classParam + " " + integerParam);
    }

    static Stream<Arguments> integerParams() {
        return withClassParams(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource
    void objectParams(String classParam, Object objectParam) {
        System.out.println(classParam + " " + objectParam);
    }

    static Stream<Arguments> objectParams() {
        return withClassParams(List.of(new Object()));
    }

}
```

3 class parameters plus 3 different method parameters with different types and sizes, producing the following output:

```
classParam1 java.lang.Object@35cabb2a
classParam2 java.lang.Object@35cabb2a
classParam3 java.lang.Object@35cabb2a
classParam1 1
classParam1 2
classParam1 3
classParam1 4
classParam1 5
classParam1 6
classParam2 1
classParam2 2
classParam2 3
classParam2 4
classParam2 5
classParam2 6
classParam3 1
classParam3 2
classParam3 3
classParam3 4
classParam3 5
classParam3 6
classParam1 false
classParam1 true
classParam2 false
classParam2 true
classParam3 false
classParam3 true
```

### JUnit Pioneer

There is the [JUnit Pioneer](https://junit-pioneer.org) extension pack for JUnit Jupiter. It comes with `@CartesianTest`. Using the extended the example from above:

```java
class CartProdTest {
    
    @CartesianTest
    @CartesianTest.MethodFactory("classWithObjectParams")
    void testClassWithObject(String clazz, Object object) {
        System.out.println(clazz + " " + object);
    }

    static ArgumentSets classWithObjectParams() {
        return ArgumentSets
                .argumentsForFirstParameter(classParams())
                .argumentsForNextParameter(new Object());
    }

    @CartesianTest
    @CartesianTest.MethodFactory("classWithIntegerParams")
    void testClassWithInteger(String clazz, int integerParam) {
        System.out.println(clazz + " " + integerParam);
    }

    static ArgumentSets classWithIntegerParams() {
        return ArgumentSets
                .argumentsForFirstParameter(classParams())
                .argumentsForNextParameter(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
    }

    @CartesianTest
    @CartesianTest.MethodFactory("classWithBooleanParams")
    void testClassWithBoolean(String clazz, boolean booleanParam) {
        System.out.println(clazz + " " + booleanParam);
    }

    static ArgumentSets classWithBooleanParams() {
        return ArgumentSets
                .argumentsForFirstParameter(classParams())
                .argumentsForNextParameter(false, true);
    }

    static String[] classParams() {
        return new String[]{"classParam1", "classParam2", "classParam3"};
    }

}
```

This produces the same output.

Comment: Sort of works, but so far from elegant that I wouldn't bother with it except maybe for a very simple case. What if I have 10 parameterized tests? I'll have to repeat the same trick 10 times. Not DRY at all.

Comment: @SergeiTachenov you can extract the different sources (class parameters, test parameters, …) into separate classes and reuse them. I can't see how this violates the DRY principle. Or what do you mean?

Comment: One class, ten test methods. Method-level parameters are different (different types, different number, different sets), class-level parameters are the same. How would you do it? Can you edit your answer to provide an example with at least two test methods with different set of parameters?

Comment: @SergeiTachenov so a fixed set of class paramters (e.g. cp1, cp2, cp3) but multiple different sets of method parameters (e.g. mp1-1, mp1-2, mp1-3 and mp2-1, mp2-2, mp2-3)? Then you want to test each class parameter with each method parameter?

Comment: Yes, this is much better. I hadn't thought of extracting this Cartesian logic out of the parameters method. The example is still not general enough, though, because each test has only one method-level parameter. But it shouldn't be hard to generalize further from here.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing: this way I can't use class-level parameters in `setUp()` methods. And I can't think of a way around it, short of ditching the standard `setUp()` methods (called by the test framework) and calling a custom-made `setUp()` method manually from the test method instead.

Comment: @SergeiTachenov yeah, it's unfortunate that the parameters are not available e.g. via `@BeforeEach`. I mostly use this workaround for [cross-browser visual testing](https://gist.github.com/beatngu13/e4d756c494cb1d45496f8b4dbff27991/#gistcomment-3007617). Here I assign the parameters to fields to control them `@AfterEach`. Not perfect, but it does the job for me.

Comment: Accepting this due to the obvious lack of better solutions.

Comment: Reading the question comments, I remembered another non-DRY thing about this approach: having to write `String classParam, ` in *every* method signature. Also, edited the question to provide a better example of what and why I need.