# JUnit5 multiple sources for different arguments (cartesian product)

Tags: java, junit5, cartesian-product, parameterized-unit-test

I am trying to write a test with JUnit 5 which should test multiple combinations of some parameters. Essentially I want to test some cartesian product of inputs from different sources. Consider the following test:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvFileSource;
class CartesianProductTest {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvFileSource(resources = { "values.csv" })
    void testIt(int input, int expected, int otherParameter) {
        assertEquals(expected, methodUnderTest(input, otherParameter));
    }
}
```

The problem is now that I only have `input` and `expected` in the `values.csv` and the `otherParameter` should be tested for some fixed values that `methodUnderTest()` always returns the expected value for all these values. Somehow I have to provide a cartesian product of all the values in my CSV and all the values `otherParameter` can take. I looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57648088/7962200 but this needs to either hardcode all my test cases or read the CSV manually to provide a Stream of the values. I thought more of something like

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvFileSource;
class CartesianProductTest {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource
    void testIt(int input, int expected, int otherParameter) {
        assertEquals(expected, methodUnderTest(input, otherParameter));
    }

    static Stream<Arguments> testIt() {
         return csvValues().flatMap(csv ->
             otherParams().map(otherParam -> Arguments.of(csv, otherParam)));
    }

    @CsvFileSource(resources = { "values.csv" })
    static Stream<Arguments> csvValues() {/* get somehow from Annotation */}
    @CsvFileSource(resources = { "otherparam.csv" })
    static Stream<Arguments> otherParams() {/* get somehow from Annotation */}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For my use-case I was able to do something like this:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class SampleTest {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource
    void testSomething(List<String> list) {
        System.out.println(list);
        // do something
        // assert something
    }

    private static Stream<List<String>> testSomething() {
        List<String> one = Arrays.asList("waz", "yaz", "zaz");
        List<String> two = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar");
        List<List<String>> product = Lists.cartesianProduct(one, two);
        return product.stream();
    }
}
```

You would have to read your .csv into some `List` or something similar. Of course getting the name of the .csv from an annotation could be a challenge; maybe [Custom Annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5#8-custom-annotation) could help, but I did not dig that far.

Possibly also worth looking at: [Introduce ArgumentsProvider that computes the cartesian product of collections of datapoints](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1427), which will lead you to [JUnit Pioneer](https://github.com/junit-pioneer/junit-pioneer).

Comment: JUnit Pioneer is what I always see when people start talking about caresian products.  Worth expanding out into its own full, separate answer

Comment: @M.Justin Unfortunately JUnit Pioneer is not an option for me. Something about corporate security policy. :(